# Downloading multiple files from URL using R not working

Tags: r, bash, url, download, wget

I am trying to download multiple NetCDF (.nc) format files from multiple URLs in a loop. However, when I try to open the files, they seem to be corrupted.

You will find my code below. I have tried different methods, for instance, using download.file or system.

This is an example of the files I need to download:
http://thredds.met.no/thredds/catalog/metusers/senorge2/seNorge2/provisional_archive/PREC1d/gridded_dataset/201601/catalog.html

But I need to download hundreds of files, since each file represents a day.

Here's my code so far:

```
year = c("2016","2017")
mon = c("01","02")
day = c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10",
        "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
        "21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31")
for (y in year){
  for (m in mon){
    for (d in day){
      download.file(paste("http://thredds.met.no/thredds/fileServer/metusers/senorge2/seNorge2/provisional_archive/",
                          "PREC1d/gridded_dataset/",y,m,"/seNorge_v2_0_PREC1d_grid_",y,m,d,"_",y,m,d,".nc",sep=""),
                    destfile=paste("seNorge_v2_0_PREC1d_grid_",y,m,d,"_",y,m,d,".nc",sep=""),method="curl",mode="wb")

      #try(system(paste("wget ",paste("http://thredds.met.no/thredds/fileServer/metusers/senorge2/seNorge2/provisional_archive/",
      #                               "PREC1d/gridded_dataset/",y,m,"/seNorge_v2_0_PREC1d_grid_",y,m,d,"_",y,m,d,".nc",sep=""),sep=""), 
      #           intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE, wait=TRUE))
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Best,

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your code I get in some files `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`. To retry the download in this case add `--retry-on-http-error=503`. Maye also add `--random-wait`. I changed the `method` from `curl` to `wget` and removed `mode="wb"` as the manula says *Not used for methods ‘"wget"’ and ‘"curl"’*. Hope the following solves your problem.

```
year = c("2016","2017")
mon = c("01","02")
day = c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10",
        "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
        "21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31")
for (y in year){
  for (m in mon){
    for (d in day){
      download.file(paste("http://thredds.met.no/thredds/fileServer/metusers/senorge2/seNorge2/provisional_archive/",
                          "PREC1d/gridded_dataset/",y,m,"/seNorge_v2_0_PREC1d_grid_",y,m,d,"_",y,m,d,".nc",sep=""),
                    destfile=paste("seNorge_v2_0_PREC1d_grid_",y,m,d,"_",y,m,d,".nc",sep=""),method="wget",extra="--random-wait --retry-on-http-error=503")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say that the file is 'corrupted'? How are you trying to read the `nc` files?

Your code seems to work and I can read the downloaded files. You can use the `raster` package in R to read the file. Please also ensure you have the `ncdf4` package installed.

```
library(raster)
r = raster('seNorge_v2_0_PREC1d_grid_20160101_20160101.nc')
```

Comment: I read `nc` files with `CDO`, `ncview`, `R`, etc. The solution given by @GKi above solved the problem. What was happening before is that the files "appeared", but they were virtually empty - as if they did not download completely.